# MYSQL: return value associated with highest number with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, sql-limit

In my table I have entries ordered by a `timestamp`. I want to return a single entry that has the highest `timestamp`.

This works:

```
SELECT max(`timestamp`) FROM `messages`
```

However, it returns just the `timestamp` value. So I try to select the `message` value too:

```
SELECT max(`timestamp`), `message` FROM `messages`
```

I get this error:

```
In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'database.messages.message'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

So I add a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT max(`timestamp`), `message` FROM `messages`
GROUP BY `message`
```

However this just ends up returning every value in the table.

I understand GROUP BY is supposed to unify identical entries, I just have absolutely no clue why I'm forced to use it in this situation and how to just get the latest entryrather than all of them.

Comment: A simple way to solve non aggregated columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578865/439171

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to return a single entry that has the highest timestamp.

Don't aggregate. You can sort and limit instead:

```
select * from messages order by timestamp desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below mysql query. first inner query get the highest number. after that outer query remove data repetition.

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `timestamp` 
  FROM
    `messages` 
  ORDER BY `timestamp`) 
GROUP BY `timestamp`
```